# How can I assign one value to column by js in RadGrid

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I have Radgrid with all rows always in edit mode. I want following functionality in one of the columns: after item is edited, all rows in this colum take this value. Here is how my column looks like.

```
  <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Opis" HeaderStyle-Width="125px" ItemStyle-Width="120px"
                            UniqueName="poz_nazwa">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "poz_nazwa")%>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" ID="Rtopis" DataTextField="poz_nazwa" DataValueField="poz_nazwa"
                                    Width="120px" Text='<%#Bind("poz_nazwa") %>' onfocus="javascript:podp(this.id);"
                                    AutoCompleteType="Disabled" onpropertychange="Opisblur()">
                                </telerik:RadTextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

And here is what i tried and is not working:

```
        function OpisBlur() {
            if (event.propertyName == 'value') {
                var grid = $find("<%=RadGPozycje.ClientID %>");
                var masterTableView = grid.get_masterTableView();
                var iloop;
                if (masterTableView != null) {
                    var gridItems = masterTableView.get_dataItems();
                    var i;
                    for (i = 0; i < gridItems.length; ++i) {
                        var gridItem = gridItems[1];
                        var cell = gridItem.get_cell("poz_nazwa");
                        var controlsArray = cell.getElementsByTagName('input');
                        if (controlsArray.length > 0) {
                            var rdo = controlsArray[0];
                            rdo.value = "valueofchangeditem";                         
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
```

There are two most obvious problems with my approach:

1. I change only selected item, not all. When i try to use masterTableView.get_editItems()  IE says that there is no such method.
2. This code produce stack overflow since function occurs on propertychange, and inside of it i change property.

Can you help me find solution to implement desired functionality?

Answer (score 0):

In your ItemTemplate for the column, can you put a label or something that has a className?  Then wouldn't you be able to update everything on the page that has that class with the new value?

```
$('.poz_nazwaClass').val("valueofchangeditem");
```

If you don't use jQuery, adding a tag then, element.getElementsByTagName('poz_nazwaTag') then loop through the elements I think.